# How to fix invalid use of group function error?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query which is giving the error in the title. But I'm not sure what is the reason for this or how to fix it?

I'm trying to find the ids of countries with the presidents with the maximum salary

```
select c.id from country as c
inner join president as p on c.pid = p.pid
join president as p2
on p.salary = max(p2.salary)
```

Tables:
President(pID: int, salary: int)

country(cID : int, pID : int)

Comment: Which SQL?  MySQL 5.x, MySQL 8, Oracle, SQL Server, SQLite, PostgreSQL, etc, etc?

Comment: mysql is the one

Comment: ***MySQL 5.x*** or ***MySQL 8***?

Comment: Please include the full error message in the body of your question.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `max(p2.salary)`in the `ON` clause of a join. This shows you misunderstand what a join does. The `ON` clause looks at two *rows* (the left and the right; in your case a country row and a president row) in order to decide whether to join them, i.e. keep the row consistng of the two or dismiss the pair. While there is a salary in the president row, this is just one value. `max(salary)` makes no sense here hence. You cannot use aggregation functions in the `ON` clause. (The same is true for the `WHERE` clause by the way.)

What you want is countries with presidents earning the maximum salary. So we select from countries where the president has the salary that is the maximum salary of all salaries. One way to translate this into SQL (quite literally):

```
select *
from country
where president_id in
(
  select president_id
  from president
  where salary = (select max(salary) from president)
);
```

Of course you can also join the tables. You would especially do that if you wanted to show the presidents, too:

```
select *
from country c
join president p on p.president_id = c.president_id
where p.salary = (select max(salary) from president);
```

Or you could tell the DBMS to select all countries with their presidents and salaries and then sift through this list in order to keep only those lines with the maximum salary:

```
select *
from
(
  select c.*, p.*, max(p.salary) over () as max_salary
  from country c
  join president p on p.president_id = c.president_id
)
where salary = max_salary;
```

There are still other ways to get the same result, e.g. using `EXISTS` instead of `IN`, or getting the maximum paid presidents by asking "WHERE NOT EXISTS a higher salary", or ranking the rows with `RANK` or `DENSE_RANK`, etc.

(I've named the president IDs `president_id` for readability. This also makes it easier to avoid or spot typos as you had in your original request. If you want to stick with your abbreviations, simply rename `president_id` to `pid` in all my queries :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are using a group aggregation function `max(p2.salary)` without using any grouping. You need to do the grouping in a subquery.

To get the country that pays their president the most, use a query like this:

```
select c.cID, p.salary 
from country as c
inner join president as p on p.pID = c.pID
inner join (
    select max(salary) as maxsalary
    from president) as p2 on p.salary = p2.maxsalary
```

Note that if multiple countries pay the same as the maximum salary to their president, all these countries will be returned.

Comment: This will return each country together with its highest paid president.

Comment: Yes and I need the countries who's presidents get paid the maximum salary among all presidents.

Comment: Are you trying to find the country which pays their president the most, or are you trying to get the highest paid president for each country?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I have updated my question with table info. Your second answer is what I was looking for.
But I don't understand how your columns are named. example getting p.salary 
from country and I can't run it myself

Comment: Okay, I have updated the query as per your column names, this should run now. The salary is coming from the president table, not the country table; we aliased the president table to p , so p.salary = president.salary. We are getting a list of countries (`from country as c`), then joining that with the president table for those presidents for that country (`inner join president as p on p.pID = c.pID`) so that we have a list of presidents for the countries. Then we use a subquery to find the maximum salary paid to any president and select the president(s) that have that maximum salary.

Answer (score 0):

To get the country which pays its president more than other countries pay their president...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  country    c
INNER JOIN
  president  p
    ON p.pID = c.pID
WHERE
  p.salary = (SELECT MAX(salary) FROM president)
```

Or...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  country    c
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT
    *,
    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY salary DESC)  AS rn
  FROM
    president
)
  p
    ON p.pID = c.pID
WHERE
  p.rn = 1
```

In both cases, if multiple presidents are tied for having the highest salary, all of those presidents (and their countries) are returned.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to use your first answer. But president does not have countryID as a column. My tables are in the question.

Comment: I also do want all the countries that have presidents tied for the max salary